# awk: how can the code collect substring

Tags: awk

Forgive me if this is not a usual question.
I am using a code to get the substring before n'th field separator:

```
echo '123-321-333-111-235'| awk -F"-" '
BEGIN {n=3}
{for(i=1;i<=n;++i)  
k = k (k=="" ? "" : FS) $i; 
print(k) 
}'
```

This gives

```
123-321-333
```

I dont understand how the line `k = k (k=="" ? "" : FS) $i;` work. 
It the `k=k` and `$i` around the ternary operator that puzzles me.
My question is simply to get an explanation

Comment: Can you be more specific what part of the line you don't understand? The [field separator designator](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Field-Separators.html)? The [ternary operator](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Conditional-Exp)? Addressing fields by the numbers with `$i`? String concatenation?

Comment: Also the question seems to have a mistake, you only iterate through 2 fields, so the result of your command should be `123-321`.

Comment: Or you could use `cut` instead of `awk` - `n=2; echo '123-321-333-111-235' | cut -d'-' -f1-$((n+1))`

Comment: @vovick I dont get the construction around the ternary operator, the `k=k` and `$i`. (And sure, its n=3 to produce the result)

Comment: @roaima yeah with the `cut`- just trying to learn awk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
echo '123-321-333-111-235' |
awk -F'-' -v n=3 '
  {
     for( i=1; i<=n; ++i )
        k = k (k == "" ? "" : FS) $i
     ;
     print k
  }
'
```

The `for` loop runs 3 times:

`i=1:`

```
 k is empty, $i -> $1 -> 123

 k <= empty ( empty == empty ? empty : "-" ) 123

 k <= empty empty 123

 k <= "123"
```

`i=2:`

```
 k is "123", $i -> $2 -> 321

 k <= "123" ( 123 == empty ? empty : "-" ) 321

 k <= "123" "-" "321"

 k <= "123-321" due to the implicit concatenation property of awk strings
```

`i=3:`

```
 k is "123-321", $i -> $3 -> 333

 k <= "123-321" ( 123-321 == empty ? empty : "-" ) 333

 k <= "123-321" "-" "333"

 k <= "123-321-333"

 This value of k is now sent to stdout.
 STOP.
```

Alternatively you could also do the following:

```
n=3

echo '123-321-333-111-235' | sed -ne "s/-/\n/$n;P"

echo '123-321-333-111-235' | perl -F- -lane "\$, = '-'; print @F[0..$n-1]"

( 
   var='123-321-333-111-235'
   set -f; IFS='-'; set -- $var

   for((i=1;i<=$n;i++))
   do
      v=${v-}${v:+"$IFS"}$1
   done
   echo "$v"

   # or, alternatively:
   N=$#
   while case $# in `expr $N - $n` ) break ;; esac; do
     V=${V-}${V:+"$IFS"}$1
     shift
   done
   echo "$V"
)

var='123-321-333-111-235'
FS='-'; # field separator provided here
fields=$(yes "[^$FS]*$FS" | head -n $n | tr -d '\n')
result=`expr "$var$FS" : "\($fields\)"`
echo "${result%?}"
```

Comment: Ah I think it sunk in by now - I think it was the initial value of `k` that troubled me the most, that you can assign a value ( =k ) that does not exist yet.

Comment: This is called the phenomenon of `autovivification` whereby the mere act of using a variable creates & initializes it.

Comment: Note if input is more than one line, unlike the example given, the awk in the Q doesn't reset `k` and produces a cumulative result, while your sed and perl methods do each line separately. awk can also do the equivalent of the perl method because assigning to `NF` or any `$fld` regenerates `$0` automatically: `echo... | awk -F- 'BEGIN{OFS=FS} NF>3{NF=3} 1'`

Answer (score 0):

If you had `k = k $i`, it would add in every iteration currently processed field at the end of `k` (so you would get: 123321333).

If you had `k = k FS $i`, you would get -123-321-333.

The ternary if only makes sure, there's not dash at the beginning, because when awk process $1, k is empty and thus ternary if returns "".

Comment: Hm, I accept that you can do something like  `k=k` - but still dont get it - is it  a variable assignment, or  ?

Comment: @user3375672, yes it's the same as `i = i + 1`. If a variable name is on the right hand side, it gets replaced by its value, if it's on the left it is assigned. So `k=k` literary means get the value of `k` and assign this value to `k`.